# Passing dependencies to a module angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, controller, dependencies

So I am somewhat new to angular, but not javascript. I am working with an app someone else wrote and am trying to create a new controller in an existing module. The controllers are almost identical to each other as far as dependencies go. The question I have is how do I pass the same dependencies to both controllers? It seems like you would be able to pass them in like this:

```
`angular.module('ApertureForm', ['dialogs.main','dialogs.default-translations','ui.bootstrap'])`
```

When I do that for both modules, the controller returns undefined for whatever reason. Thats where I get stuck. How do you pass in dependencies such as the above code? Any advice would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`angular.module('ApertureForm', ['dialogs.main','dialogs.default-translations','ui.bootstrap'])` tells AngularJS to initialize an Angular module named `ApertureForm` and also load other Angular modules as dependencies *for the module*.

To add dependencies to a controller, you do something like the following:

`angular.module('ApertureForm').controller('ControllerName', function($scope, $location, $timeout) {...});`

`angular.module('ApertureForm')` = Get the module named ApertureForm.

Then create a controller called `ControllerName`. The closure is where you inject dependencies.

To prevent a controller's dependencies from getting renamed on minification, you can do:

```
angular
    .module('ApertureForm')
    .controller('ControllerName', ControllerName);


    ControllerName.$inject = ['$scope', '$location', '$timeout'];

    function ControllerName($scope, $location, $timeout) {...}
```

Docs: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di

Comment: Ok, that makes total sense. Can you explain what the second argument is for the module? for instance `angular.module('ModuleName', [])`

Comment: `angular.module('ModuleName', [])` is the `setter` and `angular.module('ModuleName')` is the `getter`.  The array is for any dependencies, but even if there are none, must be passed in to `angular.module` to set / create a module.

Comment: @JeffNeal take a look the Dependency Annotation section in this link: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di

Answer (score 0):

In `angular.module('ApertureForm',[` you list the modules you want to inject to your module. You list in once for each module you have. If You want to create a controller in one of your modules, then your can use:

```
var myApp = angular.module('ApertureForm');

myApp.controller('GreetingController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.greeting = 'Hola!';
}]);
```

$scope here is a dependency for controller

You can read more about it [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller)

Answer (score 0):

AngularJS [Controllers](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller) and [Dependency Injection](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di):

```
angular
    .module('ApertureForm', ['dialogs.main','dialogs.default-translations','ui.bootstrap'])
    .controller('FormController', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) { 
        // FormController code...
    }])
    .controller('WebinarController', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
        // WebinarController code...
    }]);
```

Comment: But this is the problem I am having that I don't quite understand. Perhaps I used the wrong lingo. `angular
    .module('ApertureForm', ['dialogs.main','dialogs.default-translations','ui.bootstrap'])
    .controller('MyController', ['$scope', 'depService', function($scope, depService) {
        // your code...
    }]);`   if I try to create another controller under the same module such passing in the same second argument to the module, it fails.

Comment: Created an example on how to work with Controllers and Dependency Injection in AngularJS; also added the links to the official documentation.. Do you have installed all the dependencies? Are you getting some error in console? Can you show the code of the controller you have created?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/EPZLtHkn Creating another controller under the same module name with the same arguments passed in totally fails. The only real difference between the two is the controller name.

Comment: In the same AngularJS module `ApertureForm` you can have multiple controllers.. See my answer have been updated

Comment: So if it's passed into the module period, it should be available, right? I think thats where my missing link is. Because the module should be aware of the other dependencies being passed in no matter what. The controller is a second thought at that point. Perhaps it should have been declared differently as well. Maybe like    `angular.module('ApertureForm', dependencies);`    Then declare my controllers in either another file or independently of that code block. I get it now. Makes total sense!

Comment: One more thing is that (in http://pastebin.com/EPZLtHkn) you have to properly close the `[` in you controllers: `controller('WebinarController', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) { ... }]);`

Comment: Yep sure, you can create a variable for your module: `var apertureForm = angular.module('ApertureForm', dependencies);` And than you can add controllers, services, directives, in different files with their respective dependencies.. like this: `apertureForm.controller('FormController', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {...}]);` and so on...

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to everyone for the help! All of it was very useful in learning the structure of angular and how to properly use the framework. @Yosvel Quintero was able to explain how the module works and why I was getting the error. When dependencies are passed into the module, not the controller, they are available to all controllers as it the module it's self is now aware of the dependencies, which is why I kept getting errors trying to pass them again. Hopefully the answers given in response to the question can help someone learn angular as well. Thanks guys!